# What happens when you get items for leveling up but your backpack is already full?

Tags: pokemon-go

When you level up you get some free goodies, but what happens to those if your backpack happens to be full at that time?

Are the new goodies lost?
Are some (random) items in your backpack discarded or can you choose which ones?
Or something else?

Answer (score 6):

You'll get them anyway. It happened to me a couple of times (because my backpack is always full) and I end up with an overfull backpack (like 380 out of 350 items). So don't worry about having a full backpack when levelling up.

Comment: For further info, having an overfull backpack will cause you to be unable to gather items from PokéStops.